# NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having issues with saving an author object in my db. It was working fine yesterday, so I'm not too sure where the issue came in.

Here is the file for:

author.rb

```
#
# Table name: authors
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string           not null
#  website    :string
#  influences :string
#  bio        :text             not null
#  died       :date
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  birthday   :date             not null
#  photo      :string
#

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  has_many :books
  has_many :genres, through: :books, source: :genres

  validates :name,     presence: true, length: { in: 2..30 }
  validates :bio,      presence: true
  validates :birthday, presence: true
  validates :genres,   uniqueness: true

end
```

Let me know if I should add any other files, I'm not having issues creating users - just with authors it seems so far.

Thank you!

Comment: please show the place that raises the error and full stacktrace

Comment: sure thing!


```NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
from /Users/evanmedrano/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:125:in `method_missing'``` -----This is after I tried saving an author into the db

Comment: I figured it out! There is an issue with this line
```validates :genres,   uniqueness: true```

so ill need to fix that, but the original issue is addressed. thanks!